# Parent class destructor deletes child classes with outside initiated elements?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Spaceship.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>


class Position {

public:
    Position (std::string Name, double x, double y, double z);

private:
    std::string Name;
    double x, y, z; //Coordinates on a 3D map


};

class Flight {

public:
    Flight (Position *Start, Position *End);
    ~Flight();

private:
    Position *Start;
    Position *End;

};


class Spaceship {

public:
    Spaceship (std::string Name, Flight *flightPlan);
    ~Spaceship();

private:
    std::string Name;
    Flight *flightPlan;

};

class Universe {

public:
    Universe ();
    ~Universe ();

    void addSpaceship (Spaceship *Spaceship);

    private:
        std::vector <Spaceship*> *Spaceships; // A vector of Spaceship pointers
        std::vector <Spaceship*>::iterator start, end;
        int numberOfSpaceships;

};
```

Spaceship.cpp

```
#include "Spaceship.h"

Position::Position (std::string Name, double x, double y, double z) {
    this->Name = Name;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}


 //------------------------------------------------------------

Flight::Flight (Position *Start, Position *End) {
    this->Start = Start;
    this->End = End;
}


Flight::~Flight () {
    delete this->Start;
    delete this->End;
}



//--------------------------------------------------------------

Spaceship::Spaceship (std::string Name, Flight *flightPlan) {
    this->Name = Name;
    this->flightPlan = flightPlan;
}

Spaceship::~Spaceship () {
    delete this->flightPlan;
}

void Spaceship::printFlightPlan () {
    std::cout << "Spaceship name: " << this->Name << std::endl;
    this->flightPlan->printFlightPlan();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

Universe::Universe () {
    this->Spaceships = new std::vector <Spaceship*>();
    this->start = this->Spaceships->begin();
    this->end = this->Spaceships->end();

    this->numberOfSpaceships = Spaceships->size();
}

Universe::~Universe() {
    delete this->Spaceships;

}

void Universe::addSpaceship(Spaceship *Spaceship) {
    this->Spaceships->push_back(Spaceship);
    this->start = this->Spaceships->begin();
    this->end = this->Spaceships->end();
}


int main (void) {   

    Position *Start = new Position("Home", 45.566, 34.5677, -12.4565);
    Position *End = new Position ("Far Far Away", 67.4564, -56.6765, 23.4565);

    Flight *virginFlight = new Flight(Start, End);

    Spaceship *sp1 = new Spaceship("Virgin Mary", virginFlight);
    Spaceship *sp2 = new Spaceship("Something else", virginFlight);


    Universe *alpha = new Universe();

    alpha->addSpaceship(sp1);
    alpha->addSpaceship(sp2);


    delete alpha;

    return 0;
}
```

ALright, this should be the the cleanest version of my code. It only has constructors and destructors. If I missed some variables / functions, please assume they are there. This compiles and runs just fine. My only problem is memory leaks.

Valgrind reports allocs > deletes by a factor of 2 at least.

Comment: "calling delete on the parent class calls children's destructors" - `Spaceship` isn't a parent class.

Comment: You're writing: `delete Spaceship;` do you mean `delete sp1;`?

Comment: Shaktai: Fixed. 0x499602D2: misused "parent" to say that it contains other classes.

Comment: Every `new`/`new[]` needs a matching `delete`/`delete` otherwise you have a memory leak. The data members in your classes are pointers, not objects, thus they don't have destructors to call. If an object is created with `new`, its lifetime isn't bound to a scope or an object. You need `delete` to end its life.

Comment: Is there a way to call desctructors of pointers? EDIT: delete the object referenced by that pointer

Comment: `delete` calls the destructor of the pointed-to object.

Comment: The idea is that I'm creating a "chain reaction" where a desctructor of a class delete[] its private objects --> those objects destructors are called --> this goes on up until everything is deleted. So why am I getting memory leaks above?

Comment: Because you're only deleting `sp1` but not `start` `end` or `flight`?

Comment: Hmm..actually I don't seem to have memory leaks anymore, I think I'm getting it from somewhere else.

Comment: @Aroll605, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will help us understand how the whole thing works.

Comment: "What is the proper way of doing this?" - Use smart pointers and/or value-based members and containers. In all but the rarest of circumstances (and this isn't one of them) manual memory management is simply avoidable in modern C++. This is three classes in to your project. Imagine the festival you'll be having when you're dozens or *hundreds* of classes deep in your hierarchy. Avoid this if you can (and you *can*), and exploit the tools provided for you. Unrelated: fyi, include `<cmath>`, not `<math.h>`

Comment: You should almost never use the `delete` keyword, unless you're implementing a specialised resource management class (which you aren't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In deed Your program leaks. This is due to std::vector of Spaceship* in your code. an STL vector container will manage and free it's internal memory only when it contains objects not pointer to objects.

Here when you add Spaceship to your vector and did delete alpha will not release the memory pointed by sp1 and sp2 in your main program.

In modern C++ you should avoid any use of raw pointer and in stead try to use smart pointers. Here I tried to change your code and I Thought now will not leaks.

SpaceShip.h

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Position {

public:
 Position(std::string Name, double x, double y, double z);

private:
 std::string Name;
 double x, y, z; //Coordinates on a 3D map


};

class Flight {

public:
 Flight(Position *Start, Position *End);
 ~Flight();
 void printFlightPlan();
private:
 Position *Start;
 Position *End;

};


class Spaceship {

public:
 Spaceship(std::string Name, Flight *flightPlan);
 ~Spaceship();
 void printFlightPlan();

private:
 std::string Name;
 Flight *flightPlan;

};

class Universe {

public:
 Universe();
 ~Universe();

 void addSpaceship(std::shared_ptr<Spaceship>);

private:
 std::vector <std::shared_ptr<Spaceship>> *Spaceships; // A vector of Spaceship pointers
 std::vector <std::shared_ptr<Spaceship>>::iterator start, end;
 int numberOfSpaceships;

};
```

```html
#include "Spaceship.h"

Position::Position(std::string Name, double x, double y, double z) {
 this->Name = Name;
 this->x = x;
 this->y = y;
 this->z = z;
}


//------------------------------------------------------------

Flight::Flight(Position *Start, Position *End) {
 this->Start = Start;
 this->End = End;
}


Flight::~Flight() {
 /*delete this->Start;
 delete this->End;*/
}

void Flight::printFlightPlan() {
 
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------

Spaceship::Spaceship(std::string Name, Flight *flightPlan) {
 this->Name = Name;
 this->flightPlan = flightPlan;
}

Spaceship::~Spaceship() {
 delete this->flightPlan;
}

void Spaceship::printFlightPlan() {
 std::cout << "Spaceship name: " << this->Name << std::endl;
 this->flightPlan->printFlightPlan();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

Universe::Universe() {
 this->Spaceships = new std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Spaceship>>;
 this->start = this->Spaceships->begin();
 this->end = this->Spaceships->end();

 this->numberOfSpaceships = Spaceships->size();
}

Universe::~Universe() {
 //delete this->Spaceships;

}

void Universe::addSpaceship(std::shared_ptr<Spaceship> Spaceship) {
 this->Spaceships->push_back(Spaceship);
 this->start = this->Spaceships->begin();
 this->end = this->Spaceships->end();
}


int main(void) {

 Position *Start = new Position("Home", 45.566, 34.5677, -12.4565);
 Position *End = new Position("Far Far Away", 67.4564, -56.6765, 23.4565);

 Flight *virginFlight = new Flight(Start, End);

 std::shared_ptr<Spaceship> sp1(new Spaceship("Virgin Mary", virginFlight));
 std::shared_ptr<Spaceship> sp2(new Spaceship("Something else", virginFlight));


 Universe *alpha = new Universe();

 alpha->addSpaceship(sp1);
 alpha->addSpaceship(sp2);


 delete alpha;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) That's terrific!